# Facebook app page banner in app center

Tags: facebook

how can i change the default banner of my facebook app in app center like some other apps ?
when you open this link :
https://www.facebook.com/games/manage
some of apps have custom banner. but some one (and mine) have a gray default banner. 
I filled all of the icons and banners in the app details of my facebook app.

Comment: Which banner are you talking about?

Comment: the apps in this link have banner https://www.facebook.com/games/manage